# WiFi interface does not starts on boot

Tags: wireless, network-manager, ifconfig

I was toying around with `hostapd` and I don't know what I did but now on rebooting my wifi is not starting.
`ifconfig` shows all the interfaces but the `wlan0`. 
Right now I am using a workaround by running : `sudo iw phy phy0 interface add wlan0 type managed` everytime I boot.
How can I fix this?

Comment: Seems if you do not know what you did no one else may either.

Comment: Which Ubuntu version is in use?